# Drawing to the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm creating a website that lets the user draw to the background with a color he chooses. I also want to let the user to change the background color with a hex color picker tool.

The latter is easy but how can I let the user draw to the background? Is it possible to use canvas as the background?

Should I create the whole background entire of small divs which color I would change when the user is drawing?

Comment: If the user can pick one color I should work with a simle `div` placed on the background but if he can draw with more than one color I would use things like `<sgv>` or `<canvas>`

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: If it's in the background, you will probably have a problem with z-index layering. Why is it in the background if it's to be drawn upon? Should we assume you will place more content on top of it that is not to be drawn upon?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning there is a [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) library that can expedite your canvas drawing. If your needs are simple this is a quick solution, especially for prototyping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is indeed to use a `<canvas>`.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWHfOVfqI89Nc3xUMY-q-7f0) you can find a in-depth tutorial about how to use HTML5 Canvas to create a Drawing App. Good luck.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Flesh out your answer so that if the link disappears in the future there's still something of value here.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the best way is to create a canvas as background. According to the support you will give to IE (well, if you need IE8-), use [excanvas](https://github.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas).

1. Create a canvas and position it using CSS (or position the content on it, whatever)
2. Bind the color picker and update the canvas accordingly (using clearRect and then filling with a new rectangle with the color you chose)
3. You're done!

You'll need to check:
    
    
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var canvasWidth = 100; // Get it here.
        var canvasHeight = 100; // Get it here.
        ctx.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "YOURCOLOR";
        ctx.fill();

Don't forget to update the dimension of your canvas for the responsive part if yo uneed it!

If the user updates the color, then clear the rectangle using:

```
ctx.clearRect()
```

Then, set the new color again.